Mautic integration extension can't be install
I am using latest version of CiviCrm in my WordPress website and want to install mautic integration from here https://civicrm.org/extensions/mautic-integration, but when I try to install this extension just blank white screen appears and when I refresh page a error occurred "Unknown extension"
Is that this extension won't supporting in new version of CiviCrm or other things is conflicting. I want to use this extension.

Feel free to reach out to us (we are the extension maintainers) info @ vedaconsulting.co.uk
